# Looking for a text editor without blinking cursor

Tags: linux, editors

I'm looking for a text editor that enables people to disable
the blinking cursor(aka prompt)(or doesn't have a blinking cursor altogether).

It's not an easy question to answer with a google search.

I've tried searching through many different text editors settings. In command prompts we can disable the blinking cursor, and for me
with a high FPS monitor I guess it's more pronounced and annoying
than most people would recognize, but anyways I was hoping maybe someone out there knew of one.

I'm looking for a regular text editor as opposed to a terminal based one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's start the editor wars again...

Emacs allows you to disable the flashing cursor.

Comment: thank you guys... i can't believe I never noticed the option in emacs before, I spent 5 minutes with it. customized the theme, turned off the blinking cursor, and changed it from a block to a vertical bar, now I am happy I have a good text editor I can actually use to get things done. I never noticed how full featured it was in the past, it looks like you can access more settings than any other text editor right from the gui with a couple clicks... awesome

Answer (score 4):

The [nano editor](https://www.nano-editor.org/) has a non-blinking cursor. It's available with most distros and is often preinstalled.

For a GUI option you could look at [Scite](https://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) or Notepad++. Scite has an option to disable cursor blinking by editing a config file. Notepad++ provides a slider in the editing preferences.

Many other GUI editors provide similar options.

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for a regular text editor as opposed to a terminal based one

Comment: @MarkThomas You'll want to add that to your question then.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

1. Open the command prompt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
2. Type `settings` to `Open User settings (JSON)`
3. Set `"editor.cursorBlinking"` to `"blink"`, `"expand"`, `"phase"`, `"smooth"`, `"solid"`.

```json
{
  "editor.cursorBlinking": "solid",
  "editor.cursorStyle": "block"
}
```